# how to add zeros to string in php

Tags: php, string, format, zero

I have strings: `23-65, 123-45, 2-5435, 345-4`
I want to add zeros to them so all of them will look like `###-#### (three digits dash four digits): 023-0065, 123-0045, 002-5435, 345-0004`
How can i do it in php?
Thanks!

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split them using

```
$parts = explode('-', $number);`
```

then use [str_pad](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function:

```
$parts[0] = str_pad($parts[0], 3, "0");
$parts[1] = str_pad($parts[0], 4, "0");
```

and then concatenate them again

```
$number = implode('-', $parts);
```

Alternatively you can pad them using `vsprintf`:

```
$number = vsprintf('%03d-%04d', $parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$str = "23-65, 123-45, 2-5435, 345-4";
$numArray = explode(",",$str);
$str_new = "";

foreach($numArray as $nums) {
  $nums = explode("-",$nums);
  $num1 = str_pad($nums[0], 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $num2 = str_pad($nums[1], 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $str_new .= $num1."-".$num2.",";
}
$str_new = rtrim($str_new,",");
```

Output:

```
023-0065, 123-0045,0 2-5435, 345-0004
```